# Why doesn't this subprocess.check_call() work?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I'm running these snippets with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.

```
import subprocess
args = ['rsync', '--rsh="ssh"', '/tmp/a/', '127.0.0.1:/tmp/b/']
subprocess.check_call(args)
```

Fails

```
import subprocess
args = ['rsync', '--rsh="ssh"', '/tmp/a/', '127.0.0.1:/tmp/b/']
call_string = ' '.join(args)
subprocess.check_call(call_string)
```

Works

The first code snippet results in rsync getting an invalid command line.  Using the short version of this option (`-e`) doesn't make any difference.  If I remove the `--rsh` part it works fine.

Using `shell=True` doesn't make any difference.  Eliminating the quotes from "ssh" doesn't make any difference and I'd like to keep the quotes so I can pass arguments to ssh.

What's the problem?

Comment: the 2nd command should fail. If it works then somewhere `check_call()`  (or function that it uses) has been redefined with `shell=True`. Try the first command with `shell=False` (the default). Look at `print(inspect.getsource(subprocess.check_call))`

Comment: BTW, do you need this option at the first place? My `rsync` always used `ssh` on ots own for the last 10 years or so...

Comment: @glglglg: In the end I want to add some arguments to the ssh instance that rsync initiates.

Comment: I repeat: `subprocess.check_call('rsync  --rsh=ssh ...')` should fail on Ubuntu with `No such file or directory` because the string argument is interpreted as a program name. If `shell=True` makes no difference then there is something wrong with how you test your code. To pass additional arguments to `ssh`, move it to a separate argument e.g., `['rsync', '-av', '-e', 'ssh -l ssh-user', 'rsync-user@host::module', 'dest']`. Also check that `rsync://` or `host::module` are not missing.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes around `ssh`; the shell would normally have parsed those and passed on the argument *without* the quoting:

```
import subprocess
args = ['rsync', '--rsh=ssh', '/tmp/a/', '127.0.0.1:/tmp/b/']
subprocess.check_call(args)
```

Comment: Eliminating the quotes doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @JivanAmara: For what it is worth, the call works for me, on Debian.

Comment: What Python version / OS are you using?

Comment: Debian stable; Python 2.6, and Mac OSX 10.7 with Python 2.7